# Mutation observer does not work when given in window.addEventListener("load" function () {});

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

This is the perfectly working mutationobserver code :

```
var overlay = document.createElement('div');
overlay.setAttribute("class", "banner");

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type == "childList")  {
      var elem = document.getElementById('banner');
      if(elem) {
        elem.parentNode.insertBefore(overlay, elem.nextSibling);
        observer.disconnect();    
      }
    }
  })
})

/// The part I'am going to put inside window.addEventListener("load" function () {}); ////

var elemBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
observer.observe(elemBody, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
})
```

Above code is given in a js file that is inside the body of the Html, works fine. I want to move the js file into the head of the Html. So putting the same code in head throws an error as elemBody is not loaded at the time of execution.

```
var elemBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];  ///this line throws error
```

So I gave a window.addEventListener("load" function () {}); so that the body loads and then mutation observer starts observing, But it's not working.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  var elemBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    observer.observe(elemBody, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
    })
});
```

Comment: how is it not working with the event-listener? you still getting an error?

Comment: @Homungus It was working fine before the EventListener , when i wrap the part specified above in EventListener it does not work

Comment: so i see: first you had your code in the body without event listener - all works fine. then you put your code in head - `getElementsByTagName` throws an exception. then you put your observer.observe method in the `window.load` and you get an exception again?

Comment: @Homungus Exactly ! I don't know if it's even possible for observer.observe method to work inside window.load

Comment: did you check if your event-listener gets called at all? like with an console.log in your event-listener body? 
do you have some more code to share, e.g. your markup etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [document.onreadystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState),

**Try this**

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        // Your code 
    }
}
```